# SQL - Return row if Boolean is True

Tags: java, sql, boolean

Im trying to create an SQL Statement that will differentiate between employees types. For example if the Boolean Type Manager Column is checked it will return. Im using the info to fill a Manager on Duty JCombo in Java.

Im trying

```
String sql = "SELECT Employees.Name FROM Employees WHERE Manager = 'true' ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

Cant seem to get it right.

Comment: What's the type of the column `Manager` ?

Comment: Can yoiu add sample data?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error? If yes which one? If not what *is* the problem?

Comment: its a Boolean Type and the help worked. Thanks

Comment: its offtopic just advice. You can use aliases in Java also. It makes your code clear. `SELECT e.Name FROM Employees e ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL the boolean field will be a bit so your SQL statement will need to be

```
String sql = "SELECT Employees.Name FROM Employees WHERE Manager = 1 ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

Comment: SQL (the query language) does not use `1` or `0` for booleans. It uses `true` and `false`.

Comment: This works fine so he seems correct. SQLite Database using Java JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

in `SQL` a boolean field is a bit field (0 or 1) so you have to check as:

```
String sql = "SELECT Employees.Name FROM Employees WHERE Manager = 1 ORDER BY Name ASC"
```

Comment: It that _really_ was a `boolean` then it should be `where manager` or `where manager = true`. In SQL (the query language) boolean literals are `true` and `false` not to be confused with the character literals `'true'` and `'false'`

Comment: Until the OP tells you what's the type of the field, this is a wild guess (most certainly the right one, but still, a boolean can be stored using many, and often weird, ways).